# jeditable onblur function

Tags: jquery, function, jeditable

I am using jeditable but want to use a function to save the data on the client.  This works fine, but I also want to use a function to handle the onblur event.  My code is as follows:

```
$('#answerlist li').editable(function(value, settings) {
            OnAnswerTextEdit(this, value);
            return (value);
        }, { onblur: function(value) {
            OnAnswerTextEdit(this, value);
        }
        });
```

It sort of works, but the jeditable edit window does not close following the onblur event.  Does anyone know how I can close the edit session on loss of focus, or somehow grab my changes via a function when the edit textbox loses focus.  I do not want to submit a form at any time - I want to keep all changes local.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the following to solve the problem (used reset() to close the editor, but applied the changes 'manually' by setting the html:

```
$('#answerlist li').editable(function(value, settings) {
            OnAnswerTextEdit(this, value);
            return (value);
        }
        , { onblur: function(value) {
            OnAnswerTextEdit(this, value);
            this.reset(value);
            $(this).html(value); 
            return (value); }
        });
```

Comment: This bypasses the input validation for 'onsubmit'. Any idea, how to apply it.

Comment: `onsubmit : function(settings, td) {
 var input = jq(td).find('input');
 jq(this).validate({
  rules : {
   'value' : {
    digits : true
   }
  },
  messages : {
   'actionItemEntity.name' : {
    number : 'Only numbers are allowed'
   }
  }
 });
 console.log("this: %o", this);
 return (jq(this).valid());
},`